# mySql update query return ERROR 1242: 1242: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I have realy strange error.
when I run

```
 UPDATE `courseriesdb`.`files` set isProtected=1 where id=105;
```

I get the error:
**Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row    0.062 sec**
Which is strange, that this error reads only in certain records,
The following command, for example:

```
 UPDATE `courseriesdb`.`files` set isProtected=1 where id=100;
```

does not cause any error.
files table:

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `token` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `isProtected` int DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

The only difference between record number 105 and record 100,
Is that in record 105 the value of the field token is 'b6d8cf9af75faec429199a6150aa38a094547332',
and in record 100 there is no value in the field token.

**In fact, I can not make any update on record number 105,
But I did not understand what this has to do with the token value, which seems to have caused the line to lock from changes**

Comment: Are you using any triggers on that table?

Comment: yes, but how is it related?

Comment: Okay, so this was resolved when I removed the triggers.
Probably really the problem with them,
Thank you!

Comment: If you share them, others could have a look at them